# Ajax code to send user data to php page that updates the edited row of a table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, datatable

So I have this table:

```
<?php             
  echo '<table id="tableteste" class="table table-striped" width="100%">';
  echo '<thead><tr>';
  echo '<th>Data Chamada</th>';
  echo '<th>Hora Chamada</th>';
  echo '<th>Unidade</th>';
  echo '<th>Observação</th>';
  echo '<th>Solicitante</th>';
  echo '<th>Coletadora</th>';
  echo '<th>Data Coleta</th>';
  echo '<th>Hora Coleta</th>';
  echo '<th>Protocolo</th>';
  echo '</tr></thead>';
  echo '<tbody>';

  $stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT *, date_format(data_chamada, "%d%/%m%/%Y") as data_chamada, date_format(data_coleta, "%d%/%m%/%Y") as data_coleta FROM coleta_hc_2017 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100');
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['data_chamada'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['hora_chamada'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['unidade'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['observacao'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['solicitante'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td id="coletadora">' . $row['coletadora'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td id="data_coleta1">' . $row['data_coleta'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td id="hora_coleta">' . $row['hora_coleta'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td id="protocolo">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</tbody></table>';
?>
```

And a plugin to enable users to edit this table, the problem is I can't manage to handle the data inserted by the user, I'm trying to use Ajax to do that, here's my code:

```
var table = $('#tableteste').DataTable();

function  myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "include/edita.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:,
        success: function(data){
    alert(data);                                 
         }
     });
   }
```

But as you can see I don't know how to set up the "data" field, tried a lot of different stuff but none worked, can you guys help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement this function.

```
function tableToArray(table){
    var result = [];
    for(var y=0;y<table.rows.length;y++){
       for(var x=0;x<table.rows[y].cells.length;x++){
          result.push(table.rows[y].cells[x].innerHTML); // PUSH VALUE INTO ARRAY
       }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This array could then be passed on with AJAX to PHP.

**Edit 1**

Since you didn´t know how to implement this I will add one more example.

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableteste);

function tableToArray(table){
    var result = [];
    for(var y=0;y<table.rows.length;y++){
       for(var x=0;x<table.rows[y].cells.length;x++){
          result.push(table.rows[y].cells[x].innerHTML); // PUSH VALUE INTO ARRAY
       }
    }
    return result;
}

function  myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "include/edita.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: tableToArray(table),
        success: function(data){
    alert(data);                                 
         }
     });
}
```

**Edit 2**

Yes, as the OP just pointed out you need to have two different variables, one just for the function (tableToArray) and one for the plugin. I just didn´t point it out since I thought it was obvious.

**Edit 3**

Just a fix for the new problems.

In the callback, you need to edit the POST method.

```
function  myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "include/edita.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
              table_data: tableToArray(table)
              },
        success: function(data){
    alert(data);                                 
         }
     });
}
```

I just want to point out that you might need to swap the name table_data, to what you are fetching using `$_POST[]`.

Comment: Ouch, I'm afraid I won't know how to implement that, where exactly do I send those data to my php page?

Comment: Nice, it looks promising, except by the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MakeCellsEditable' of null". It happens when I mix the ajax call with the plugin that turns the table editable, I fixed by editing the first line of the code, here's the full code: https://pastebin.com/ePd6Ximy.

Comment: Now I think my php page is not properly set, before your call I was working in a different way, now I don't really know how the data get's out of the ajax call, at first I was seting the variables that will go to the php page, how does it work now? Here's my php page: https://pastebin.com/4KbqwWA4